# Get coordinates of specified text on current screen

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, hook, automated-tests

all.
i wanna write a tool for GUI automation which can locate text label on current screen(the absolute location) so that i can drive the mouse cursor to click on it.
The signature of the needed function should like  this:

Point GetTextCoordination(string text)

Any one have an idea how implement this? I don't wanna use the OCR or computer vision technology for performance issue. Is the hooking  of the TextOut win32api function a feasible way?

Comment: What should be its behavior when text is found many times on screen?

Comment: i think i will supply a argument which indicates the index of display order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that hooking the TextOut function is a feasible solution (though it's certainly possible).  You don't have any guarantee that the text you want to find was drawn using this function.  Trying to use OCR would be similarly fraught with difficulties.

I suspect that for your purposes, it would be sufficient to enumerate the windows of the target application (using GetWindow and related functions) and examing the text of each (using GetWindowText) to look for the one you want.  That would give you a window handle and from that you could get the window boundaries or send it a message directly.

Comment: thanks,but some text on the screen can't be extracted by spy++,so i don't think they can be get by GetWindowText function.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a GUI automation toolkit, such as the UIAutomation library or the white library (which is a wrapper around UIAutomation), or AutoIT.

(Alternatively there are commercial tools for this - if you are looking into setting up a test automation program, then you'd be better off with one of the commercial tools, as they have a lot of features that make this kind of thing easier.)

Comment: lots of text can't be get by UIAutomation's UI Spy so that UIAutomation won't help. similarly ms spy++ and QTP's Object Spy doesn't recognize a great portion of text on screen.